# No package sqlite3 available

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

New to Python, sorry if my Question found stupid but need help. I Need to install sqlite devel on my server. but when i am trying to run `sudo yum install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev` its giving the following error

```
[pythondemo@panel python3.6]$ sudo yum install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 69.72.212.11
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 69.72.212.11
 * base: mirror.jaleco.com
 * epel: mirror.texas3006.com
 * extras: mirror.jaleco.com
 * ius: ius.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: mirror.jaleco.com
No package sqlite3 available.
No package libsqlite3-dev available.
```

Comment: You don't need to install sqlite3 module. It is included in the standard library (since Python 2.5).

Comment: i am getting these error                                                                     
 `File "chatbot.py", line 8, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/home/pythondemo/.local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/home/pythondemo/.local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 50, in <module>
    version_info = tuple([int(x) for x in version.split(".")])
NameError: name 'version' is not defined`                                    
 Thats the reason i am installing.

Comment: If module not installed Error comes something like this: ImportError: No module named sqlite3

Comment: How to check that module is installed or not?

Comment: pip list or pip freeze

Comment: Thank you Noor jafri its doesn't show Sqlite3 in that list. how do i install it now?

Comment: i am sorry pip list isn't the correct way to check that. Can you run the python script or on python console just simply write **import sqlite3** and see if it works

Comment: I am getting these error thats the reason i was downloading sqlite devel `[pythondemo@panel Chatbot]$ python3.6 chatbot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chatbot.py", line 8, in <module>
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
  File "/home/pythondemo/.local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/home/pythondemo/.local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 50, in <module>
    version_info = tuple([int(x) for x in version.split(".")])
NameError: name 'version' is not defined`  dnt know what to do. can you suggest?